# Formula for coupled stripline of 100 ohm

Tags: pcb-design, differential, kicad, lvds, controlled-impedance

I am designing a PCB which involves MIPI and LVDS routing.

What is the formula to calculate the impedance of asymmetric coupled stripline for MIPI and LVDS routing (100 ohm)? The required calculator is not available in KiCad. And in the online calculators, I could not find one for asymmetric.

Attached is the PCB Stack-up details. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwMk1.png

[image]

Comment: Are you routing the LVDS traces on one of the inner layers?

Comment: Yes, as of now all the LVDS lanes are in the same layer shielded by GND in the top (L1) and In2 (L3) layers. But on the MIPI, 3 pairs are in L2 and 2 pairs are in  L3. Shielded by GND.

Comment: Saturn PCB Toolkit software should have a calculator. Check it out.